# webview cant be refresh using anyway

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, webview

i have web view and i try to give the user button to refresh but i cant set that button i try to use this code

the refresher button

```
imgbtr2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageButton imgbtr2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonr2);

        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true)"); // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
});
```

the webview

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);


webView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com/");
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); 
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

but it seems like javascript:window.location.reload(true) its not work . if i use webView.loadUrl("www.exapml.com"); it will work but this is not last Url u was there not reopen the webpage from the first url

and why webview can not open page like https://vine.co/  is it coz its not end with .com .. and how to make it open all the website .. and when u enter website like Myspace and try to login using Facebook everything will work ok until u finish login it will not show anything after u connect it to ur facebook  ,, is it coz of the redirection and if it is how to fix it

this is the last 3 thing's stop me from finishing my app . i hope someone can help

Comment: use this -> webView.loadUrl("http://m.facebook.com/"); instead of webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.location.reload(true)"); in onclick  listerner

Comment: again this will reopen the link not refresh it

Comment: yup what to refesh without loading again?

Comment: i mean if u already go to m.facebook.com/messeges 
if u do ur code it will take me back to m.facebook.com not m.facebook.com/messeges

Comment: ohh nope u need to keep track in that case of ur url and once ur url is in ur hand so u refresh page..u can use String webUrl = webView.getUrl(); on every page load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `web.reload();` method to do so.

```
imgbtr2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     web.reload();  
    }
});
```

Comment: this will reload the page or refresh it ? if the link was to Facebook then i go to messages will it reload me to facebook or to the messages where i was ?

Comment: it will reload/refresh the page where you are. That is if you load index.html first than go on contactus.html and press refresh it will reload contactus.html.

Comment: i will give it try and come back to here if its work i give u best ans , can u look to my other Question , and why webview can not open page like https://vine.co/ is it coz i ... up

Comment: ok its work , even the javascript:window.location.reload(true) also work , it was my wrong , i used onReceivedError to hide the page not found error and i was change my Url to local webpage so when i refresh it it will open the local html wish i thought  it not refreshing , how idiot it was from me, anyway any idea how to avoid the page not found error ?

Answer (score 0):

Call again

```
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
```

so the full code would be

```
newButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
dgeActivity.this.mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.facebook.com");
}});
```

Comment: this is reload not refresh

Comment: Yes this is reload you can use dgeActivity.this.mWebView.reload() to do it.